# MySql Use replace() in if() condition

Tags: mysql

I have tried:

```
SET @my_var = 'one,two,three';
SET @to_replace = 'two,';
SET @my_check = 1;

SET @my_var = SELECT IF(
    ISNULL(@my_check),
    @my_var,
    REPLACE(@my_var, @to_replace,'')
);
```

I have tried also `SET @my_var = IF( ...` Or `SELECT REPLACE` instead `REPLACE` in condition

*But got syntax error*

What I expect is:

If `@my_check = null` so `@my_var = 'one,two,three'` (still unchanged)

Else replace `two,` with `''` but using `@to_replace` variable

Expected result: `@my_var = 'one,three'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @my_var = if(isnull(@my_check), @my_var, replace(@my_var, @to_replace, ''));
```

Works well in MySQL v8.